# Is it possible in Delphi to declare a TDictionary with a Generic value type?

Tags: delphi, generics, tdictionary

Can Delphi make the following statement?

```
TDictionary <T, TList <T>>
```

The compiler doesn't like it:

> Undeclared identifier: 'T'

I have added in the `uses` clause:

> System.Generics.Collections;

**UPDATE:** With this code I have these problems:

```pascal
interface

uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TListado = class(TObject)
  private
    FListado: TDictionary<T, V: TList<T>>;
    function GetListado: TDictionary<T,TList<T>>;
    procedure SetListado(const Value: TDictionary<T, TList<T>>);
  public
    property Listado: TDictionary<T,TList<T>> read GetListado write SetListado;
    function ReadItems(Cliente: T):TList<T>;
  end;
```

I changed the unit code but before it worked, I don't know what I'm failing in.

> Undeclared identifier: 'T'

Comment: In what context? If `T` is coming from a higher context, ie a Generic class with a `TDictionary` data member, then it should work fine. Can you provide a [mcve] showing what exactly you are having trouble with?

Comment: If you want to extend generic dictionary class you probably want `TDictionary<T> = class(TDictionary<T, TList<T>>)`

Comment: Or if you want to constrain secondary generic type to `TList<T>` use `TDictionary<T, V: TList<T>> = class`

Comment: @jmontegrosso for future reference, such important details belong in your main question, not in comments. I have moved them for you this time. Next time, please be more diligent about asking complete and detailed questions up front.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how Generics work.  I strongly suggest you [read the documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Generics_Index) more carefully.

You are trying to use `TDictionary` in contexts where specific instantiations of the class are needed. In the code you have shown, the compiler is correct that `T` is an unknown type with which to instantiate your use of `TDictionary`.

Everywhere you are using `T`, you need to specify an actual type that you want to use with the dictionary, for example:

```pascal
interface

uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TListado = class(TObject)
  private
    FListado: TDictionary<Integer, TList<Integer>>;
    function GetListado: TDictionary<Integer, TList<Integer>>;
    procedure SetListado(const Value: TDictionary<Integer, TList<Integer>>);
  public
    property Listado: TDictionary<Integer, TList<Integer>> read GetListado write SetListado;
    function ReadItems(Cliente: Integer): TList<TInteger>;
  end;
```

Otherwise, you will need to declare `TListado` itself as a Generic class with its own parameter, which you can then use to instantiate `TDictionary`, and then you can specify a type for that parameter when instantiating `TListado`, eg:

```pascal
interface

uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TListado<T> = class(TObject)
  private
    FListado: TDictionary<T, TList<T>>;
    function GetListado: TDictionary<T, TList<T>>;
    procedure SetListado(const Value: TDictionary<T, TList<T>>);
  public
    property Listado: TDictionary<T, TList<T>> read GetListado write SetListado;
    function ReadItems(Cliente: T): TList<T>;
  end;
```

```
var
  list: TListado<Integer>;
begin
  list := TListado<Integer>.Create;
  ...
  list.Free;
end;
```